# Optional readonly property or getter in abstract class

Tags: typescript, typescript4.0

This code was valid for typescript 3, but in typescript 4 it produces an error

> 'smth' is defined as a property in class 'A', but is overridden here in 'C' as an accessor.

Yes, it is listed in breaking changes, but here is a bit specific case. Base class `A` declares an optional readonly property and never create it. It's logical, that it should not care about the way how it is implemented in child class.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3gKAUIQAcoB7CAU3koBMEpLhayA7ZATwTAFsIALAPwAuBKwCuPEJSh4CRYuJDIAlrAQAzABQBKXPKJFYbMGWSUAdMjIBzLQJVgLvAToMIAvni94UaDABCCJQAHlSstBjY+IYu-AgAvAgAjAAM3nJ+6AgAwsFhlBFR+oY2lIhxurgM5eJQrAgAssACFjARZDxVXj5ZGAAi+eGRWPo+rJQA7ggBuhbabhPTOXMLeEsI-au6QA)

```
abstract class A {
    protected readonly smth?: number

    public f() {
        console.log(this.smth)
    }
}

class B extends A {
    smth = 10
}

class C extends A {
    get smth() { return Math.random() }
}

class D extends A {
}

new B().f()
new C().f()
new D().f()
```

I was thinking about marking property as `abstract` in class `A` - it solves problem with different overrides in `B` and `C` but introduces error in `D`:

> Non-abstract class 'D' does not implement inherited abstract member 'smth' from class 'A'.

As the property is optional, I don't want to require child classes to implement it and I want any implementation (with property or with getter) to be valid.

**So what can I change in class `A` so that all 3 classes (`B`, `C` and `D`) will be valid?**

Number of such child classes in my project is

```
B - 16
C -  2
D - 90
```

so I definitely don't want to change `D`, also I can't change `C` to `B` as they are calculating dynamic value. Changing to getter as to the most rare variant seem not very logical too, but at last has some sense. But currently I've marked property in `C`-classes by `@ts-ignore`.

Comment: You can't redeclare an instance member as accessor property or the reverse. TypeScript is trying to prevent you from introducing a bug. Given `class A {x = 1}`, `class B extends A {get x() {return 5;}}`, the following will always print `1`: `console.log(new B().x)`.

Comment: And I don't know why anyone would downvote since this was not an error until TypeScript 4.0. It could have been an error from day 1 because it is broken code. This is a language improvement

Comment: @AluanHaddad, in your example it would be exception (in strict node), not 1. But the problem happens because you have both - property with assignment and getter. In my case base class never assigns (and never creates) property, it just has the declaration like interface member or abstract property, so it won't cause any problems.

Comment: It does not fail in strict mode. Why would it? It's true that in your example, it would not fail, but that's a minor edge case and, critically, if you compile with `--useDefineForClassFields` so that your class is compatible with the latest ECMAScript class features, the declaration itself _will_ create a field with the value `undefined`

Comment: @AluanHaddad, it will as getter goes to prototype, so at the moment of assignment in the base class getter from the child will already be awailable. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8Ae0C80CMBfAUKSMAQtAKZIAuJAdgCYzwIDmJ50SAFAJSIBOLArjyrQArAG4suYAHsqEaSBIA6ENMbsqJAO7RCXJUk5A) - `[ERR]: Executed JavaScript Failed: 
[ERR]: Cannot set property x of # which has only a getter` - fails both for ES2017 and ES5. But if I set `useDefineForClassFields` or run code with classes in browser, I'll get `1` as you wrote.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, yep, with `useDefineForClassFields` even optional field is compiled into property. Seems like the actual feature I want to have is not field overriding, but ability not to override `abstract` property if it is optional. But actually with `useDefineForClassFields` even abstract property is compiled into `defineProperty` :( For me it seems strange as it makes `abstract x?: number` and `abstract x: number | undefined` the same thing - property always exists.

Comment: Yeah, I was running in the browser with class field support. Good catch but I think the point stands. Regarding `abstract` property emit under `--useDefineForClassFields`, that could be a bug. My personal but strongly held opinion is that abstract classes are a misfeature as are accessibility modifiers. They conflict with JavaScript on a fundamental level. What's worse is that they tend to give new users weird ideas about TS. TS is great but it could do without these features. Anyway, I digress. Even if the abstract field wasn't defined, introducing a subclass of B would break things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221696/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-aluan-haddad).

Comment: Created feature request https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40635. Also created related bug https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40632.